# Impossible to upgrade my current production app because of different SHA1?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, sha, android-app-bundle

3 weeks ago I upgraded my app on playstore without any problem.

Now I have an error when I add my appbundle in production

Your Android App Bundle file has not been signed with the correct key. Make sure to use the SHA1 signing key:49:32...

Since the last upgrade, I haven't made any changes to my key.jks. I didn't regenerate it, use windows restore or android restore ... I just added flutter code to the lib folder.

I don't now if it's normal but when I verify SHA1 in Gradle script and signing report I have a different SHA1 than what playstore shows me in the error.

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\utilisateur\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...
SHA1: B5:69:...
SHA-256:...
Valid until: vendredi 6 mars 2048
```

My keystore was create the 6 mars 2018 for 30 years validity
during this 2 years I havn't change my key, I have done al my upgrade with no problem. Just now in 2021 ...

How can I do to match with the SHA1 of playstore ? I really want to just upgrade my app. not create a new app

thank you

Comment: It seems you are using the debug key instead of the production key.

Comment: OK,  but how can I modify debug to release and match with the demanded SHA1 from playconsole ? I'm very affraid to regenerate a new thing that forced me to recreate a new app. I touch nothing between two ugrade :( thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the key for you and then you will be able to publish future updates.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.